# "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" when updating vendors in a symfony app while deploying on a remote server

Tags: server, permissions, php, sql

I am trying to deploy my symfony application on a remote amazon server. While updating the vendors using: `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` command this error occurs `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Screen-shot of the remote server terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your database password in `app/config/parameters.yml` file, to match the actual database password for your application. It appears that current parameters are the default ones (user "root" with empty password)

Comment: Thank you. Without using Elastic beans, I used an AWS EC2 remote server and uploaded the code. And the logged into the remote machine deployed the app.